# Android Opengl Vertex greater than 1

Tags: android, opengl

I'm working in Android to do a polygon of which I have the vertices, the problem is that, there are vertices greater than 1 and them are floats.

I have seen a code in which the value of one is handled in this way:

```
int one = 0x10000;
```

I have floating values like this:

```
float verticesflotantes[]={//Arreglo de Vertices Flotantes
                  1.0000f,    1.0000f,    4.2361f,
                  1.0000f,    1.0000f,   -4.2361f,
                  1.0000f,   -1.0000f,    4.2361f,
                  1.0000f,   -1.0000f,   -4.2361f,
                 -1.0000f,    1.0000f,    4.2361f,
                 -1.0000f,    1.0000f,   -4.2361f,
                 -1.0000f,   -1.0000f,    4.2361f,
                 -1.0000f,   -1.0000f,   -4.2361f,
                  4.2361f,    1.0000f,    1.0000f,.... continue...
```

but the vertexarray i need is an int, and I try this:

```
int vertices[] = new int[verticesflotantes.length];

        for(int i = 0;i<verticesflotantes.length;i++){
            // 1 = 65536
            // 5 = 1 = 65536
            // 5 = 65536
            // x = x*65536/5

            float regla3 = verticesflotantes[i]*65536/5;

            String hexadecimal = Float.toHexString(regla3);

            vertices[i]= Integer.parseInt(hexadecimal,16);
}
```

but this gives me an error:

Invalid int: "0x1.99999ap13"

[image]

help I'm confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got NumberFormatException because you parse an "float string" in `Integer.parseInt(...)` function.
Maybe you can do something like:

```
int regla3 = (int) verticesflotantes[i]*65536/5; // get the integer part
// well... now you have integer part, I think there is nothing we need to do.

vertices[i] = regla3;
```